# Stickit dynamic binding for newly created select element

Tags: jquery, marionette, jquery-select2, backbone-stickit

In my project I am using Marionette with stickit for two way data binding.

In there I need to clone div element which has select and textbox.

```
var $template = $('#template-clone');
var $clone = $template.clone();
$clone.show();

var observeSelectID = $clone.find('select').attr('id');
var selectID = '#'+observeSelectID;
```

after that I am trying to bind newly created element using stickit.

```
this.addBinding(null, {
    selectID : {
        observe : observeSelectID,
        initialize : function($el) {
            $(selectID).select2({
            });
        },
    },
    selectOptions : {
        collection : function(data) {
            var option = "{Label value pair JSON String}"   
            return {
                'opt_labels' : ['List'],
                'List' : option
            };
        }
    }
});
```

But any changes in the select box won't trigger model changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:
Add the handler for select2 stickit.

```
Backbone.Stickit.addHandler({
        selector : 'select.select2',
        initialize : function($el, model, opt) {
            var e = 'change:' + opt.observe,
                self = this;
            $el.select2();
            var up = function(m, v, o) {
                if (!o.stickitChange)
                    $el.trigger("change");
            };
            this.listenTo(model, e, up);
            this.listenTo(model, 'stickit:unstuck', function() {
                self.stopListening(model, e, up);
            });
        }
    });
```

and when new element is created add its bindings

```
            var textareaObserve = $('#textarea').attr('id');
            var textareaID = '#' + textareaObserve;

            self.bindings[selectedID] = observeSelectID;
            self.addBinding(self.model, selectedID, observeSelectID);
```

will make select2 bindings.